# Vanitygen to run 24/7 at VPS

Tags: vanitygen

I searched for tutorial to run Vanitygen 24/7 on VPS. However, I'm not able to find any that work. I have a VPS running on Debian 7. I want to use this VPS to search for Bitcoin private key 24/7.

How do I run vanitygen 24/7 on a Debian 7 VPS?

Comment: With what purpose? The answer is something annoying like "just don't stop it".

Comment: @Bitcoin Perhaps OP is asking how to install and run it? OP?

Comment: Use gnu screen!

Comment: @Wizard Of Ozzie, yes I mean how to install and run it 24/7.
@ Jonas Schnelli, I tried to use screen command to run vanitygen. However, it dont work. Also, what is "'gnu' screen" - what I'm using is just "screen".

Comment: GNU screen is the implementation of screen application available on Linux operating system. Different, compatible, screen implementations may exist on other operating systems.

Comment: If the command does not work please edit the question and include full information how you run the command and the error output.